# One controller can be reached but others cannot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

**Main Application Class**: (It was going to be using JSP but realized the trouble with Spring Boot):

```java
package com.MBS.Consulting.jsp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="com.MBS.Consulting.jsp")
public class SampleWebJspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SampleWebJspApplication.class);
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleWebJspApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**WelcomeController** - In sub folder of main class (this controller is accessible):

```java
package com.MBS.Consulting.jsp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "static/index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/Home")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome/welcome";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/ContactUs")
    public String contactUs() {
        return"Welcome/contact_Us";
    }

    @GetMapping("/AboutUs")
    public String aboutUs() {
        return "Welcome/about_us";
    }
}
```

**CustomerController** - Does not even show that it is called with AOP. The package name is the same as the last controller. I do need to login using Spring Security to reach this page. It allows me to login and then gives me 404.

```java
package com.MBS.Consulting.jsp.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.MBS.Consulting.jsp.entity.Customers;
import com.MBS.Consulting.jsp.entity.Users;
import com.MBS.Consulting.jsp.services.CustomersService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Customer")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomersService customerService;

    @GetMapping("/Home")
    public String customerHome() {
        return "Customer/Customer_Home";
    }
}
```

**Security config**:

Not sure if I really need this or not but added it just to make sure that it couldn't be causing the problem.

```java
package com.MBS.Consulting.jsp.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.scrypt.SCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoSecurityConfig {
    // add a reference to our security data source

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("securityDataSource")
    private DataSource securityDataSource;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> {
                try {
                    auth
                        .antMatchers("/Admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .antMatchers("/Billing/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "CUSTOMER", "EMPLOYEE")
                        .antMatchers("/Contacts/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "EMPLOYEE")
                        .antMatchers("/Customer/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "CUSTOMER")
                        .antMatchers("/Order/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "CUSTOMER", "EMPLOYEE")
                        .antMatchers("/Plan/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "CUSTOMER", "EMPLOYEE")
                        .antMatchers("/Services/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "CUSTOMER", "EMPLOYEE")
                        .antMatchers("/Welcome", "/Login").permitAll()
                        .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .and()
                    .logout()
                        .permitAll()
                        .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                        .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        )
        .httpBasic();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**Project structure**:

I hope the image shows up due just to show the project structure and that I believe the controllers are in the correct location to not be a problem for Spring Boot.

[image: Project Structure]

I do get a 404 Error. The web address I visit is `http://localhost:8080/Customer/Home` to try to call `CustomerController`. I am unsure what will cause this and if someone could explain what I did wrong.

I did search on it and I was going to try and configure the dispatcher servlet but it should of been auto configured. I believe if it reaching one it should be able to reach the other if it is the same folder. Also I understand the it needs to be in the sub folder of the main class. Finally I checked to see if it was the mapped right since I used folders in the template folder.

Comment: please dont post images of code/logs

Comment: Sorry  @Toerktumlare about posting the console information. I was just trying to get clarification on the fact that aop isn't catching the call to the controller in the same package as the other working controller, and was trying to use that to provide the most information for those who took the time to help. I appreciate you letting me know and will not do it again. With that being said would that point me in the direction to be able to debug or figure out the situation?

Comment: @dur I am trying to understand, I used the default config for spring boot because it looks in /resources/templates/Customer/html page(Thymeleaf). The reachable controller is /resources/templates/Welcome/html page.(was cutoff with picture but there) . Both in same location but one is shown visually and with aop but the other gives 404 like it doesn't exist. The index is in the static folder in /resources/templates/static/index.html and that works also.  Thank you in advance to everyone for their time, knowledge, and patience.

Comment: @Que1101 What about `/access-denied`? Could you call it directly in your browser? Does it exists? BTW: Are you logged in?

Comment: @dur The /access-denied page is not accessible  anymore, I tried to make custom page along with login. Then all of the pages and mappings work for welcome controller and the html pages in resources/templates/welcome, when I tried to switch to Customer controller it would ask for login in then would give 404, now I do not get that even. Could it be something with my security? Should I get ride of security and try and see if they work from there? Thank you for sticking with me!

Comment: @dur it is my security filter chain, when i comment out the page I am still able to login in as soon as i visit the site with db. is there something wrong with my security filter chain?

Comment: `In the logs for console I get no information at all when visit` please dont post your interpretation of the logs. Instead enable debug logs, and post the logs in full, as in the entire startup procedure and one request to the service showing the error. Developers work with logs, thats why they are there so that we can see what is happening.

Comment: I removed the logs

Answer (score 0):

While mappings were correct and the project structure is correct it was unable to reach controllers due to spring security. The security FilterChain in the screen shot is missing two asterisks on the permit all controllers.

this:

```
.antMatchers("/","/Welcome", "/Login").permitAll()
```

should be:

```
.antMatchers("/**","/Welcome/**", "/Login/**").permitAll()
```